# WebSphere 8.5 web service deployment

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, jax-ws, websphere-8

I have created a web service with @WebService annotation then I package it in war archive with a simple web.xml file containing displayname tag.

I have deployed it on WebSphere 8.5.5.3 server and it deployed successfully with deploy web service option, but then when I tried to go to address in browser ex: 
    http://    localhost:9080    /(context-root)/ServiceNameService

it shows me that ServiceNameService file not found and in the ffdc log there is a message:

```
[12.11.14 17:22:51:890 UZT]     FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException             SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -IOE ProbeId:1044
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: Файл не найден: /DailyCursWeatherService
    at     com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:930)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:484)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3878)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

Reporter:null
```

I tried to change classloader order from parent first to parent last and I checked a virtual host mappings
I've read another similar posts but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you provide the full web.xml? Check the namespace and the version attribute of the web-app element in web.xml -- you could be using servlet version prior to 2.5.

Comment: Yes, it uses version 2.4 is it wrong?

Comment: Yup, that means that WebSphere is running your application in J2EE 1.4 compatibility, JAX-WS with @WebService support is from Java EE 5 Servlet API 2.5 onward. You could probably upgrade the namespace/version to the latest, or remove the web.xml entirely to get it working.